# Custom WebApi Skill does not populate index

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to Azure Search, and I am currently setting up an environment to index images based on certain details.
I have set up an index that has, among other fields, a collection of complex fields I named `details`.

To populate the `details` field, I have set up an Azure Function as a WebApiSkill on my indexer, that receives the `uri` as input and returns the `details`.

[According to the example from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-create-custom-skill-example), the function receives a `application/json` `POST` request as follows:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "recordId": "1",
            "data": {
                "uri": "..."
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

..and promptly returns an `OkObjectResult` with the corresponding `json` response:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "recordId": "1",
            "data": {
                "details": [
                    {
                        "detailName": "...",
                        "detailRatio": "..."
                    }, {
                        "detailName": "...",
                        "detailRatio": "..."
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

My problem is, even though I followed the documentation on how to setup a custom skill for an indexer's skillset, and even though all of the above seem properly structured, the `details` on my index's images remain unpopulated, and it just shows as an empty list.
Here are the results of an empty search on my index:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://{search}.search.windows.net/indexes('{index}')/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "aHR0CHM6Ly9yZWxhdGl...",
            "uri": "{link}",
            "details": []
        }
}
```

By following the Azure Function's execution through console logs, it's possible to see that the indexer is indeed executing it and receiving the result, so I assume it's not a connection issue or the function's code's problem.

I would like to know if this is a common occurence? And if not, what steps should I take to try and figure out why the indexer refuses to properly populate the indexes?

---

Here are some code snippets from my indexes/indexer/skillset.
I apologize for any confusion here, as some of these had to be made by code (C#) while others were made in the Azure Portal or by a POST request. To my knowledge, all of these boil down to the same, but I am currently in the process of converting all of these to POST requests.

Index:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "uri": "...",
    "details": [
        {
            "detailName": "...",
            "detailRatio": "..."
        }, {
            "detailName": "...",
            "detailRatio": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Skillset:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "skills":
  [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "uri": "https://{azure-function}.azurewebsites.net/api/{function}?code={code}",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "uri",
          "source": "/document/uri"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "details",
          "targetName": "details"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Indexer:

```cs
new Indexer(
                name: indexerName,
                dataSourceName: dataSourceName,
                targetIndexName: indexName,
                skillsetName: skillsetName,
                fieldMappings: new List<FieldMapping>
                {
                    new FieldMapping
                    {
                        SourceFieldName = "metadata_storage_path",
                        TargetFieldName = "uri"
                    }
                },
                schedule: new IndexingSchedule {
                    Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
                },
                parameters: new IndexingParameters
                {
                    Configuration = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        ["imageAction"] = "generateNormalizedImages"
                    }
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexer definition is missing `outputFieldMappings` to specify where the data for `details` should come from. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer#outputfieldmappings

The `context` of your skills is `"/document"` and `targetName` is `"details"`, so the result will be at `"/document/details"`.

```
"outputFieldMappings": [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "/document/details",
    "targetFieldName": "details"
  }
]
```

Comment: Incredible how such an important detail missed me. Thank you so very much!